# Qt Creator on Ubuntu: Running a cmake executable

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

In Qt Creator on Ubuntu, I want to create a cmake C++ project (i.e. without using qmake). So, I create a new "Non-Qt Project->Plain C++ Project (Ubuntu CMake Build)". Then, I edit the main file and CMakeLists.txt as necessary. I click on the "build" icon, which builds the program fine and creates an executable. However, when I then click on the "run" icon, the "Application Output" window gives me the error: "No executable specified."

So how do I tell Qt Creator where to find the executable?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug reported for a few months. Please read comments (specially the 2 or 3 lasts) on the ticket https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator-plugin-cmake/+bug/1299441 to find some workarounds to this issue.